# Program that reads score from file

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm new to python and need some help on how to create a solution to my problem. I've been given a `.txt` file which contains names and scores like below.

```
upg. 1 Nils Johansson 1
upg. 1 Maria Johansson 2
upg. 1 Anna Andersson 0
upg. 1 Karl Eriksson 2
upg. 1 Nils Eriksson 1
...
...
upg. 100 Anders Persson 2
upg. 100 Maria Persson 1
upg. 100 Kristina Persson 2
```

Every person (first name + last name) occurs many times. The last entry
in every row is several points (a number between 0 and 2). The program shall
print the name of the person(s) who got the most points, and how many points.

I have figured out how to read the file and how to insert each row into a list using

```
for line in f:
    tempString = line.split()
    #print(tempString)
    array.append(tempString)
```

This gives me a list containing `[['upg.', '100', 'Kristina', 'Persson', '2']...`, I somehow need to save their points and full name without any duplicates. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: So upg and 100 is to be thrown away?

Comment: From what I can understand, yes.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? Why both tags?

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect place for a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(int)
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        *_, first_name, last_name, score = line.split()
        results[f'{first_name} {last_name}'] += int(score)
```

Result:

```
{'Nils Johansson': 3, 'Maria Johansson': 2, 'Anna Andersson': 0,
 'Karl Eriksson': 2, 'Nils Eriksson': 1, 'Anders Persson': 2,
 'Maria Persson': 1, 'Kristina Persson': 2}
```

To print this in a nice way:

```
for name, score in results.items():
    print(name, "=", score)
```

which gives:

```
Nils Johansson = 3
Maria Johansson = 2
Anna Andersson = 0
Karl Eriksson = 2
Nils Eriksson = 1
Anders Persson = 2
Maria Persson = 1
Kristina Persson = 2
```

Comment: To print nicely you can do `for name, score in results.items(): print(name, "=", score)`

Answer (score 0):

What about using a dictionary with the persons names as key. Whenever we encounter a already existing name, we add the score.
You could then do something like this:

```
score_dict={}
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lsplit = line.split()
        name=' '.join(lsplit[2:4])
        if name not in score_dict:
            score_dict[name] = int(lsplit[-1])
        else:
            score_dict[name] += int(lsplit[-1])
```

Comment: The scores are `str` and not `int` so the increment will not work without converting `lsplit[-1]` in `int`.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't realized that there are no duplicate names in the content he posted... I updated the answer

Comment: Your code worked with OP example because it has no duplicates and if it has duplicates, it will not give expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary with `key` as full name and `value` as `score` and update the latest score like this:

```
result = {}
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        temp_string = line.split()
        name=' '.join(temp_string[2:4])
        if name in result:
            result[name] += int(temp_string[-1])
        else:
            result[name] = int(temp_string[-1])
 
print(result)
```

Example:

**file.txt**

```
upg. 1 Nils Johansson 1
upg. 1 Maria Johansson 2
upg. 1 Anna Andersson 0
upg. 1 Karl Eriksson 2
upg. 1 Nils Eriksson 1
upg. 1 Nils Johansson 2
upg. 100 Anders Persson 2
upg. 100 Maria Persson 1
upg. 100 Kristina Persson 2
```

**Result**

```
{
 'Anders Persson': 2,
 'Anna Andersson': 0,
 'Karl Eriksson': 2,
 'Kristina Persson': 2,
 'Maria Johansson': 2,
 'Maria Persson': 1,
 'Nils Eriksson': 1,
 'Nils Johansson': 3
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The score in the result is supposed to be their total score and not the latest.

Comment: Try the example with your code and check if it has the same output.